# Telegram-bot replies to messages from specific user in group chat (aiogram)

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram

I want my bot to reply to a certain person in chat every time he writes (in fact every 2 hrs, like regular cuddling)
e.g.

> User1: Good morning everyone

> User2: Good morning

> Bot: (reply to User2): Have a nice day!

Now i can send messages to group from bot

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="HAD")
async def cmd_dice(message: types.Message):
    await message.bot.send_message($here chat_id$, text="Have a nice day!")
```

I don't understand how I can reply to user messages if he doesn't address the bot. Is this possible?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. To get all the messages in the bot group, you need to turn off [Privacy mode](https://core.telegram.org/bots#privacy-mode). Open the [@botfather](https://t.me/botfather). Send the */mybots* command. Select the bot.
   bot_settings --> allow_groups --> turn_groups_of
2. Use the [magic_filter](https://github.com/aiogram/magic-filter)

```py
...
from magic_filter import F
...


...
@dp.message_handler(F.from_user.id.in_({42, 1000, 123123})) # 42, 1000, 123123 users id
async def message_sender(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(text="Have a nice day!")
...
```